# Shared structure for different processes

Tags: c, parallel-processing, exec, fork, shared-memory

I need to define a shared structure between different executables in C/C++. How can I do that?
in my starter.c file:

```
pid_t child = fork();
if (child > 0) {
  // Parent.
  ... // detach shared memory
  argv[0] = "./app1";
  execv(argv[0], argv);
}
else {
  // Child.
  argv[0] = "./app2";
  execv(argv[0], argv);
}
```

- start.h -> defines the shared structure
- start.c -> creates objects and fork (like the above code)
- app.c -> uses the shared structure

**UPDATE:**

- I get a segmentation fault if I define a class at *start.h*,
  create it before *fork()* in a shared-memory (using MAP_SHARED), and access a member of it (like shared_class->s) in app1.c
- **So the question is:** how to keep the class/variables as they are after exec?

Comment: This question is exceptionally unclear. Could you post some of the code that's *relevant* to the shared memory mapping, and say specifically what your obstacle is?

Comment: Suppose that I have forked and used execv similar to the code above. So, there is a starter.c file and an app.c file. How should I define a shared structure(or variable) that is accessible by all existing processes forked by this method?

Comment: Are you asking regarding a way to send/receive data between processes?

Comment: @frozenkoi: Do not need to implement a point-2-point connection. Just a shared buffer that is accessible to all processes

Comment: What is app.c and what is starter.c?

Comment: I think you want to share a struct between these two .c files. Is it so?

Comment: @Sibrajas: Yes, that is right. But as I said in other comments, I don't want to have a copy of the struct. I want to have a buffer-like object visible to all processes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a shared structure, why don't you declare it in a separate .h(header) file and include it as a header in both of your starter.c and app.c C files.

In case you have to compile them independently, you can go along and use shared memory. If your load the structure into shared memory, then both of your processes can access them with no problem whatsoever!

Comment: I want to define a shared structure for all processes. The starter.c and app.c are compiled independently. They can be thought as different processes/applications.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the answer! The method you proposed will make 2 different copies of that structure/variables. By shared, I mean visible/accessible to all processes as one entity (not copies)

Comment: @Computer_guy hello you are mistaken....reading and writing data from the shared memory does not create two diff copies....you need better understanding of C before going ahead !

Comment: I know very well what I am doing. the problem is that I don't  have yet the mechanism to share memory between my processes. If I implement that, the problem would obviously be solved!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what platform you are using.

If it is linux.
You can use [mmap](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html).

First create shared memory mapping file using [shm_open](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/shm_open.3.html).

Then mapping it in every executable you create.

Write/read your structures to/from the shared memory.

All your process can access to the same shared memory.

You may need to find some tutorial for mmap.